# Составить формулу в Excel

Tags: excel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, формулу. Сам уже устал да и времени не хватит боюсь.

Условие: имеется столбец с циферками "блин" весь столбец -5% нужно, затем если число от 0 до 999 то +58%, если от 1000 до 9999 то +48%, а если больше 10000 то +43%. Много раз пробовал, но то скобки не там, то запятые. Я уже запутался. Помогите, пожалуйста, горю.

Comment: Что сказать-то хотели? Ничего не понял. 
Моё понимание закончилось на этой мозговыносящей фразе, вроде и русские буквы: "имеется столбец с циферками "блин" весь столбец -5% нужно".

Answer (score 2):

```
=A1*ЕСЛИ(A1*0,95>10000;1,43;ЕСЛИ(A1*0,95>1000;1,48;1,58)
=ВПР(A1;{0;1,58:1000;1,48:10000;1,43};2;1)
```

Comment: А если это не просто число а итог по формуле то наверное как то по другому нужно,да?=МУМНОЖ(RC[-1];0,95)Помогите, если не трудно,пожалуйста!!!Пробую А1 менять на RC{-1} Не Помогает!!!

Comment: R1C1 или A1 это всего лишь нотация и меняется в настройках Excel'а -отжать чекбокс "Файл->Параметры->Формулы->Стиль R1C1" и все будет A1

Comment: ДЕЦ КАКОЙТО РЕАЛЬНО НЕ МОГУ...МОЖЕТ КАК ТО ПОПРОЩЕ 1 ДЕНЬ В EXCEL"E КАКОЙ ЧЕБОКС :)А В ФЙЛЕ НЕТ СТРОКИ ПАРАМЕТРЫ:)Я МОЖЕТ "НУБЛЮ" ЕСЛИ МОЙ ВОПРОС ЕЩЕ ИНТЕРЕСЕН КОМУ-ТО, ПОДСКАЖИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА.

Comment: Единственное что смог все это сделать но в три прихода и вручную, за один день может и прогресс, но препода это не устроит.Отдельно могу сделать формулы на три условия если и формулы забивал вручную, а позиций 2000, да ведь надо не проглядеть где 12 где 1122 и где 23422, вобщем все это не точно, а как в одну формулу влить еще не сообразил

Comment: @Barmaley если мне не изменяет склероз, то RC[-1] -- относительный адрес (на одну колонку меньше. В отличие от R1C1, которая A1.

Comment: олег007, кроме создания нескольких тем и невнятного объяснения - ни-че-го!
При чем здесь 12 или 1122? При чем МУМНОЖ()?
Нормально можете задачу объяснить? Какая версия Excel?

Comment: Еще один камент от автора в таком стиле и я удалю пост - задрала эта глупая переписка...